# Neo4j: Can I generate a running value in CQL?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following cql (which does not work):

```
MATCH p = (c2:Config)<-[:OVERRIDES*]-(c1:Config) 
WHERE c1['properties.name'] = 'NodeA' 
AND NOT (c2)-[:OVERRIDES]->()
UNWIND NODES(p) AS props 
RETURN props.`properties.name` as name,
PROPERTIES(props) AS properties, 
SIZE(nodes(p)) AS `index`
```

What I'm trying to do is generate an index value that either accumulates or decrements with each row. I thought maybe the number of nodes in `NODES(p)` would go up/down as the graph was processed, but it stays constant. Is there anyway to do what I want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've unwound the nodes in the path, but want to get the index of each of these nodes in the path?

You'll need to use a different approach here, as you don't get index info when you UNWIND the nodes directly. You'll need to start with the index first, and then get each node in the path via the index in the list:

```
...
UNWIND range(0,size(nodes(p))-1) as index
WITH p, nodes(p)[index] as props
...
```

Comment: Ok, it took a few changes, but I've worked it out. Thanks for the awesome tip!